How did Xander Cage open the door on the GTO?
How did Xander Cage open the door on the GTO if it doesn't have any door handles?


Are you asking about the first movie? because they show it in that movie.

On the GTO (his bonus car for the deal with Anarchy 99) there's a button behind the door mount that he presses in order to unlock and open the doors.
That scene is from the first opus of the saga. And the video shows it at 02:01.




Out-of-universe, the prop car for the film xXx had "shaved handles" with "remote solenoids". These would allow the door to be opened using a key fob, rather than using the now non-existent handles or a concealed button.

This 1967 Pontiac Lemans was used during the filming of the 2002 action adventure movie "XXX," by Vin Diesel's character 'Xander Cage', a reluctant spy for the NSA. This impressive car was built specifically for the film, by Hollywood car builder Eddie Paul, using a 1967 Pontiac Lemans modified to GTO trim level. For the intense driving action, Paul's crew installed heavy duty shock absorbers with a special suspension cross-support, four-wheel disc brakes, working side-pipes, and a 350 c.i.d. Chevy ZZ-4 crate engine. On the cosmetic end, shaved door handles with remote solenoids complement the custom color-shifting "Blasberry" paint from "House of Kolor".
Lot # 23A: XXX (2002) 1967 Pontiac Lemans "GTO" Built by Eddie Paul

